# what is the integral formulato get eulers' number

Tags: definite-integrals

I've heard that there is some sort of formula where:  $$\int_1^ef(x) dx=1$$

my question is: what is $f(x)$, and did i write the formula correctly?(i'm new here)

$$e= 2.718...$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one possibility.  Two that come to mind are:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{e-1}$;

or (more likely what you are thinking of):  $f(x)=\frac1x$